# Can anybody please describe this portion of code of the Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

I can't understand this given portion of the *Dijkstra algorithm*. I want to understand this portion of code line by line.

The code:

```
bool operator < (const DATA &p) const { return p.dist > dist; }
```

I have the basic knowledge of c/c++ code.

Comment: It is called operator overload. It overloads `<` operator in code and this function is called when you do `a < b` where `a` and `b` have the same type of some class for example. You would implement this `bool operator...` overload in this class. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool operator < (const DATA &p) const {
    return p.dist > dist;
}
```

This is less than `<` operator overloading.

You are passing `DATA &p` prefixed by `const` which means `p` is passed by reference and it can't be modified or altered inside the function.

The function started with `const {` means there will be no write/modify operation inside the method.

`p.dist > dist` means after pushing into `priority_queue`, comparing between two `Data` will follow this criteria - when `Data` having ***smaller*** `dist` will be appeared first in the priority queue than `Data` with longer `dist`. This sounds contradictory but this is true because `priority_queue` is by-default a max heap.